# GWT Windowbuilder Exception: Type UIBinder is not found

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, uibinder, windowbuilder

I have installed Eclipse, GWT and WindowBuilder. After that, I created a new Web Application Project, and in the client-folder created a new UIBinder.
I haven't touched the xml-file, and whenever I try to open it I get an error message saying "org.eclipse.e4.xwt.XWTException: Type UiBinder is not found."

In the .java-file that the UIBinder created for me the com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder import statement doesn't show any error message.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: GWT Designer is deprecated (for a little while already). I'd be surprised if you managed to get it working.

Comment: Oh that is too bad. Thanks for your reply anyways!